# How to obtain p-value from netmeta::netmetabin function in R software?

Tags: r, p-value

I'm now analysing network meta-analysis data using R software. I am using `netmetabin` function from `netmeta` package to compare each parameter's binary outcome. However, the output is reported only Odds ratio and 95% CI without reporting p-value.

This is my code

```r
library("netmeta")

m1 <- netmetabin(mi$d1, mi$n1, mi$d2, mi$n2, mi$T1, mi$T2, 
                studlab = mi$Study, sm="OR", method = "Inverse",
                prediction = TRUE, data=mi, incr = 0.5,
                comb.fixed = FALSE, comb.random = TRUE)
```

The result reported only OR with 95%CI

How can I obtain p-value from this function?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation it appears you can use one of the functions named below, you should be able to then access the components you want.

"Value: An object of class `netmetabin` and `netmeta` with corresponding `print`, `summary`, `forest`, and `netrank` functions. The object is a list containing the following components:"

You should then be able to find the p-value you want. I.e. `statistic.random`, `pval.random`: `nxn` matrices with z-value and p-value for test of overall treatment effect under random effects model (only available if `method = "Inverse"`)

There are quite a few values you can extract, see here for more details: https://rdrr.io/cran/netmeta/man/netmetabin.html